# Relation between junction and capacitance and reverse bias voltage

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

Can someone explain how junction capacitance in reverse bias voltage depends on the **rate of change** of external diode voltage(vD)?

I tried to find the answer on google but was not successful.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the "rate of change"; it depends on the absolute reverse voltage.

Comment: The relation between reverse voltage and junction capacitance is explained in **every** book about semiconductors. Also any decent University course on the subject will treat this. Also Googling for "pn junction capacitance" gives plenty of proper explanations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research

Comment: @Andyaka I am new to this platform can you please specify why this question is off-topic. This will help in future to ask quality questions. Also, I did research it on google. My question was not related to the relation of junction capacitance and reverse bias voltage. I know that they are reversely related. But it was how junction capacitance is related to the rate of change in reverse bias voltage.This was the question asked in my college exam. Also, can you specify the reason why junction capacitance doesn't depend on **rate of change of reverse bias voltage**

Comment: You did not share evidence of prior research on google. Many, many times people say they have looked here and there but, a simple typing of the question into google leads to many useful results and it's obvious they have lied through laziness or incompetence. We do not seek to teach people how to google but we do expect them to actually do some research and demonstrate that.

Comment: @Andyaka I researched it on google but was not able to find how it depends on **rate of change of reverse voltage**

Comment: Then you need to show some evidence of this phenomena being real. When someone asks a question like this I immediately think that they have got their question badly phrased or wrong. If you have (any) evidence that it exists then please demonstrate this. In other words, how do you know it depends on rate of change?

Comment: I don't know it depends or not.According to some research done and my knowledge, it should not depend on the **rate of change**. But as I am not sure, so I asked the question on this platform.

Answer (score 2):

The junction capacitance is inversely proportional to the width of the depletion region of PN Diode. With the increase in reverse voltage, the width of the depletion region increases. Hence the capacitance, C decreases. Similarly when reverse voltage decreases, the junction capacitance increases.

Comment: My question is **does it depends on rate of change of reverse voltage applied across diode**

Comment: The dependency is on the absolute value. Not rate of change.

Comment: Is there any reason behind it

Comment: Because as per capacitance formula, C is inversely proportional to d. And d is directly proportional to reverse voltage. Not rate of change of Reverse voltage.